# Expectation of a deterministic Ising model

Tags: ising-model

I am working with **deterministic** Ising model in this form

$$
  p(\sigma; W_\beta, h) \propto \exp(-E(\sigma; W_\beta, h))
$$

where

$$
  E(\sigma; W_\beta, h) = - \frac{\beta}{2} \langle \sigma, W\sigma \rangle - \langle h, \sigma \rangle
$$

and it is defined over $\{ -1, 1 \}^N$.

I want to find the expectation $\langle \sigma \rangle$.

There is no hard requirement on $W$, maybe that they are symmetric. If you have something with further assumptions, it may be helpful too.

I have been looking at TAP (Thouless-Anderson-Palmer) equations but I think they are for random coupling, not fixed like this.

Thanks!

Comment: Consider to spell out acronyms.

Comment: What are the assumption on the interaction matrix $W$? The results will be highly dependent on its structure... In addition, it might be annoying not to have an explicit temperature parameter (that is, $W=W_\beta$). Finally, writing $x$ for the Ising spins and $y$ for the magnetic field is a highly non standard and rather poor notation. As is using $d$ to denote the number of spins (usually, it denotes the spatial dimension of the supporting lattice).

Comment: I see. I come from a different background so the notation may not be similar. In fact, I am trying to find the related pointers in the field.

Comment: I could recommend [our book](https://www.unige.ch/math/folks/velenik/smbook), in particular Chapters 2 and 3. It can be downloaded for free. But there are many, many places you can learn about such things.

Comment: Yes but I have not found a source for this expectation. Can you give me a pointer?

Comment: Again, this depends on the choice of $W$. For most choices, you will not be able to get a closed-form formula. Exceptions are: the model on $\mathbb{Z}$, the model on $\mathbb{Z}^2$ at $y=0$, the model on the complete graph or on a regular tree, etc. Just a handful of cases. Of course, you can obtain convergent expansions in various regimes.